# Toastr notifications at the redirect from modal window

Tags: asp.net, toastr

I'm hoping to use Toastr in ASP.net MVC5 with modal windows. Now, when I click the button on modal window, I'm sending data to one of my controllers via AJAX call and get redirected to the home page. Unfortunately, Toastr notifications are not working in this scenario. In dev console I can see the notification when using break points, though. But with redirect it just doesn't have any time to be seeing on the page. Any suggestions how to make it stay and be visible at the redirect to another page? I'm using Toastr in .done and .fail methods of the AJAX call.

The modal window in the html file:

```
               <div class="modal fade" id="myConfirmModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            </div>
                            <div id="WorkflowConfirmModal" class="modal-body">
                                Are you sure you want to submit this transaction?
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="myID" data-val="@Url.Action("myAction", "myController", null)" data-redirect="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Yes</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The AXAJ call in the separate .js file:

```
    $('#myID').on("click", function () {
    var reviewData = {
        //... my data here
    };
    $.ajax({
            url: $('#myID').data('val'),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: reviewData,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success == true) {
                    window.location.href = $('#myID').data('redirect');
                } else {
                    $('#myConfirmModal').modal('hide');
                    bootbox.alert(
                        "<h4>Submit Errors</h4>" +
                        "<hr><p>" + data.errors + "</p>");
                }
            }
        })
        .done(function () {
            toastr.success("Success!");
        })
        .fail(function () {
            toastr.error("Something went wrong.");
        });
});
```

Comment: Do you have any code to share? It is difficult to be helpful without any code.

Comment: @kmc059000 Here is the code. Tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser is off to the races when you issue that window.location command so you have two options:

1. Route a value ALLLL the way through your controller back into your reloaded view and kick the toastr off there. (This sucks, don't do this)
2. Restructure your JS so that your window.location call happens after the toastr hide event finishes. something like so :

   toastr.error("Content", "Title", {onHidden : function() { alert("do a redirect inside this function");}});

chained Example for first time poster:

```js
var n = $('#n').val();
$('#success').click(function () {toastr.success( $('#g').val(), n, { onHidden : function() { toastr.warning( $('#l').val(), n, { onHidden : function() { toastr.error( $('#r').val(), n, {onHidden : function() { alert( $('#d').val());}, "timeOut": "900"});}, "timeOut": "900"});}, "timeOut": "900"});   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css"><input type="hidden" id="n" value="Never Gonna"><input type="hidden" id="g" value="give you up"><input type="hidden" id="r" value="run around"><input type="hidden" id="l" value="let you down"><input type="hidden" id="d" value="and desert you">

<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="success" />
```

Example for first option requested by user:

View where BTN is pushed (just append a query string param when you call the controller action - here I am just sending a request to HOME/Index and appending ConfirmS = true as a param):

```
<div class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location='/?ConfirmS=true'"> GO </div>
```

Home Controller Index Action method (add a nullable param and if it exists and is true in this case then set a viewbag param to send to our view)

```
    public ActionResult Index(bool? ConfirmS)
    {
        if (ConfirmS.HasValue && ConfirmS.Value) { ViewBag.ConfirmSubmitMessage = "weeeee"; }

        return View();
    }
```

Home Index View (check if your viewbag property exists and if it does then do something like trigger a toastr alert):

```
@if (ViewBag.ConfirmSubmitMessage != null)
{
    <script>alert('@ViewBag.ConfirmSubmitMessage');</script>
}
```

Comment: Excellent! It's working for me. Would there be a way though, to redirect a user to the home page and display the notification there? Now the modal and notification kind of waiting for each other for the time specified and then the redirect takes place. In any way, thank you!

Comment: You could add a query string parameter that your home controller/index action consumes and sets a viewbag value to pickup on your index page and trigger the toastr to fire on document ready in js. I'm heading home for the day but if you are still having issues tryign to implement that then I can post an example in the morning when I return.

Comment: Hi Travis. Would my home controller/index action fire up a viewbag/toastr each time it is triggered or just in relation to specific redirect like we are talking about? The example would be much appreciated.

Comment: @GGG Added a quick example of nullable query string passing in MVC FRAMEWORK

Comment: Thanks, Travis. With some modifications it's now working. I'm posting my final code below.

Answer (score 0):

My final code. The modal window in the html file:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myConfirmModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="WorkflowConfirmModal" class="modal-body">
                            Your text goes here.
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="myID" data-val="@Url.Action("myAction", "myController", null)" data-redirect="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { ConfirmToastr = true})">Yes</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The Home Controller/Index Method:

```
  public ViewResult Index(bool? ConfirmToastr)
        {
            if (ConfirmToastr.HasValue && ConfirmToastr.Value) { ViewBag.ConfirmSubmitMessage = "Foo"; }
            return View("Index");
        }
```

The Index.cshtml of Home/Index(). I'm using CDNs here but local taostr.js and taostr.css will do the trick:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

@if (ViewBag.ConfirmSubmitMessage != null)
{

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            toastr.success("Success.", "Thanks.", {
                timeOut: 3000,
                onHidden: function () {
                    window.history.pushState("Name", "Title", "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
 }
```

The AXAJ call in the separate .js file:

```
$('#myID').on("click", function () {
    var reviewData = {
        //... your data here
    };
    $.ajax({
            url: $('#myID').data('val'),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: reviewData,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success == true) {
                    window.location.href = $('#myID').data('redirect');
                } else {
                    $('#myConfirmModal').modal('hide');
                    bootbox.alert(
                        "<h4>Submit Errors</h4>" +
                        "<hr><p>" + data.errors + "</p>");
                }
            }
        })
});
```